# DNN7 Skin causes error on Site Settings page

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I tried to create a skin, very basic one with a nav menu and 3 panes, and I created 2 containers. Everything works fine with all pages but when I try to go Admin > Site settings it shows the error below. When I dont use this skin, it works. Thank you for any help.

```
A critical error has occured.

AssemblyVersion:7.3.1

PortalID:0

PortalName:NukeTest

UserID:1

UserName:demo

ActiveTabID:62

ActiveTabName:Site Settings

RawURL:/Admin/Site-Settings

AbsoluteURL:/Default.aspx

AbsoluteURLReferrer:http://localhost:34237/Admin/Security-Roles

UserAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36

DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke

ExceptionGUID:f85ee8b1-180e-4616-959e-94da3bf9c20e

InnerException:Selection out of range Parameter name: value

FileName:

FileLineNumber:0

FileColumnNumber:0

Method:Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.PerformDataBinding

StackTrace:

Message:

DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Selection out of range
Parameter name: value ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Selection out of range
Parameter name: value
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable dataSource)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.PerformSelect()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.DataBind()
   at DotNetNuke.Web.UI.WebControls.DnnSkinComboBox.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Ascx file for the skin:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="index" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True" Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/admin/Skins/logo.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="logo" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/admin/Skins/search.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="search" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/admin/Skins/nav.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="nav" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/admin/Skins/copyright.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="copyright" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/admin/Skins/terms.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="terms" %>

<div id="upbg"></div>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="headercontent">
            <h1>
                <uc1:logo runat="server" ID="logo" />
            </h1>
            <h2>A free design by NodeThirtyThree</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <uc1:search runat="server" ID="search" />
    <div id="headerpic"></div>
    <div id="menu">
        <uc1:nav runat="server" ID="nav" />
    </div>
    <div id="menubottom"></div>


    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentPane" runat="server"></div>
        <div class="divider1"></div>
        <div id="primarycontainer">
            <div id="primarycontentPane" class="primarycontent" runat="server"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="secondarycontentPane" class="secondarycontent" runat="server"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
            <div class="left">
                <uc1:copyright runat="server" ID="copyright" />
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <uc1:terms runat="server" ID="terms" />
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You likely need to include the source for your skin

Comment: Hello Chris, see the edit please.

Comment: If you apply any other skin to that page does the page work?

Comment: When I go to Admin > Site settings and apply Gravity skin, it still doesnt work. When I use Restore Default Skin it works again.

Comment: Should I select skins manually for each page so it doesnt change admin side?

Comment: I think you've got a problem with your site settings somewhere, very likely unrelated to the skins you choose.